# What proof of accommodation is suitable for a UK visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, proof-of-accommodation

I am applying for a UK visa from Nepal to attend my graduation in UK. I've been invited by the university. I'll be staying for 7 days. I am not sure what kind of proof of accommodation I need to show in my visa application.

Is a hostel booking from booking.com good enough or do I need to book a hotel?

Answer (score 10):

I am assuming you have not been requested to provide proof of accommodation (on the basis that if you had been you would have said so!) so refer to the [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) guidelines where in Section 4, which is:

**documents you should not send unless specifically requested**

there is, amonsgt other, items:

> hotel bookings

The rationale will be that once allowed entry it matters little where you stay, coupled with it is very easy to cancel a booking at no cost as soon as it has been presented for a visa application.

However, if you *have* been asked for proof then I can see no reason for a hostel via booking.com to be any less acceptable than a hotel booking.

Anyway, you seem to have an excellent reason ("premise") to be visiting the UK and provided you pay attention to the forms and their requirements your chances of obtaining a visa seem very good, regardless of accommodation.

Comment: Thanks. I have to attend the ceremony on 5th Dec. Will I get the visa before that as i need to travel on 3rd.

Comment: @ManishVerma In that case you need to put 3rd as your intended date of travel.